# Can AWS Data Migration Service be used to integrate non AWS SQL server with Redshift?

Tags: sql-server, replication, migration, aws, redshift

I have a SQL Server 2012 hosted on a standalone machine. I want to migrate it to my AWS Redshift (already existing data warehouse).

My question is wether it is possible via AWS Data migration service ?

I am also open to other efficient methods for migration. Currently I am doing the following steps

1. taking a backup of the SQL server DB in the standalone server.
2. uploading it to AWS-S3.
3. Droping and restoring the Db from S3 in AWS-RDS (Sql-server)

I would like this data to be present in my data warehouse i.e AWS-Redshift

Comment: i answered your duplicate question on SO yesterday and you did not reply! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781844/migration-using-aws-dms-from-standalone-sql-server-to-aws-redshift/48782325#48782325

Comment: Hi @Jon, as the question was asked here first, perhaps you would consider answering here too? It's a pretty good fit for this site.

Comment: ok done, i wonder if i will get a response from the poster

Answer (score 0):

According to the following resource link, it seems you can: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/05/aws-database-migration-service-now-supports-migrations-to-amazon-redshift/
Or 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/aws-schema-conversion-tool-exports-from-sql-server-to-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of migration within DMS

1. "one off" data migration, where the data is copied using sql
   statements
2. "continuous replication", where the "change dta capture" system on
   the source is used to capture and process just the updates.

SQL server can be used as a source for both of these types however there are caveats and limitations that should be read and understood thoroughly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html

So long as you follow the instructions and meet the limitiations that are documented then it will work great.